# transaction fail in Bitrock net (transaction execution reverted)

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, bitrock

I have developed smart contract and web3 using ethers 6.6.10
When runing a call i received error.(transaction execution reverted)
errors.js:126 Uncaught (in promise) Error: transaction execution reverted (action="sendTransaction", data=null, reason=null, invocation=null, revert=null, transaction={ "data": "", "from": "0x-----------------------------------------", "to": "0x-----------------------------------" }, receipt={ "_type": "TransactionReceipt", "blockHash": "0x18d2d66b42d9421ac9b86892e083bffbdd1e8611b690bb9d37b7ac90ac009145", "blockNumber": 8940489, "contractAddress": null, "cumulativeGasUsed": "66077", "from": "---------------------------", "gasPrice": "1000", "gasUsed": "66077", "hash": "0x408f73cdfa9742e119aafdd00daa30703c1cd55fe9242bf5218537c8d87179f3", "index": 0, "logs": [  ], "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "root": null, "status": 0, "to": "-------------------------------" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.10.0)

I want to fix this error